# Parameter effects on kinetics of esterification for bio-diesel production

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry, kinetics, temperature

I want to discuss the [effect of parameters on the kinetics of esterification for bio-diesel production](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260994815_Parametric_effects_on_kinetics_of_esterification_for_biodiesel_production_A_Taguchi_approach). In esterification process, temperature effect and molar ration are two important parameters. During conversion of oliec acid with methanol to bio-diesel, temperature contributes more than molar ratio ( happen before 70 to 80 % conversion to bio-diesel). But after 70 to 80% conversion molar ratio contribute more than temperature.

My question is why this happens. Why the contribution of temperature and molar ratio reverse after 70 to 80% conversion to bio-diesel?